# How to go back by backButton in stack navigator that is inside drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have a multiple screens that every which is a stackNavigator.
any created stackNavigator is inside drawer. 
in every screen , when press BackButton of stackNavigator's header, screen 
navigate to initialRoute always instead back to last screen.

I tested `navigation.goBack()` and `navigation.goBack(null)` and
`navigation.goBack()` and `navigation.goBack(this.props.navigation.state.key)}`

but none of these worked.
here is my code:

```
    const MenuScreenNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Menu: {
        screen: MenuScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerLeft: (
                <HeaderBackButton
                    tintColor="white"
                    onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
                />
            )
    }
```

i have multiple screen navigator such as Menu navigator: "Load", "Home",... screens.
in continue i have drawer navigator:

```
const drawerConfig = {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContent,
    initialRouteName: "Load"
   }
   const routeConfig = {
    Menu: {
        screen: MenuScreenNavigator,
        navigationOptions: { title: strings.screenName.menu }
    },
    Load: { screen: AuthLoadingScreenNavigator },

    Login: {
        screen: LoginScreenNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: () => null
        }
    },
    User: { screen: UserScreenNavigator }
   }
```

and then i create drawerNavigator:

```
   const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(routeConfig, drawerConfig)

   export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Drawer Navigation**

This navigation method provides a way to directly switch between different screens via a drawer. This slide drawer contains links to different screens of the application.

**Stack Navigation**

This kind of navigator provides a way to transition between screens and manage navigation history. When clicking on a button or a link, a new screen is put on top of the old screen. It is something like push on pop of a stack. User able to go back to the previous screens one by one from the back button.

So to be able to navigate back you at least have to put a screen over another one, so on your initial pages that you navigated using your drawer you won't be able to go back.

[image: Example]

Taking the example above you can't go back from **screen1** to **user**,  or from **screen2** to **menu**. You have to follow the stack navigator flow. For example:

- **Menu > screen1 > screen4**

then you can go back

- **screen4 > screen1 > Menu**

Now let's jump to a real example taking the above diagram:

[image]

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Menu from './pages/Menu/Menu';
import Screen1 from './pages/Menu/Screen1';
import Screen4 from './pages/Menu/Screen4';

import User from './pages/User/User';
import Screen2 from './pages/User/Screen2';
import Screen5 from './pages/User/Screen5';

import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import Screen3 from './pages/Login/Screen3';
import Screen6 from './pages/Login/Screen6';

const MenuStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
    },
    Screen4: {
      screen: Screen4,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Menu',
  }
);

const UserStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    User: {
      screen: User,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
    },
    Screen5: {
      screen: Screen5,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'User',
  }
);

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Screen3: {
      screen: Screen3,
    },
    Screen6: {
      screen: Screen6,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);

export default DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: MenuStack,
    },
    Info: {
      screen: UserStack,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginStack,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Menu',
  }
);
```

**Menu.js, User.js, Login.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../../Header';

export default class MenuScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}>
        <Header {...this.props} />
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22 }}>
            This is Menu Screen
          </Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Screen1"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen1')}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Screen1.js, Screen2.js, Screen3.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22 }}>
            This is Screen2
          </Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Screen5"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen5')}
          />
          <Button
            title="Go to Back"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Screen4.js, Screen5.js, Screen6.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen4 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22 }}>
            This is Screen4
          </Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Back"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Check out the source code: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/react-navigation](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/react-navigation).

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, maybe try [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/697#issuecomment-309359044), or one of the other solutions proposed in that discussion, see if that solves your problem.